# ReactiveCocoa: RAC Objects still in memory after all signals complete

Tags: memory-management, ios8, profiling, instruments, reactive-cocoa

I am developing an application on iOS8 based on reactive cocoa. The application mainly does network operations.

I noticed that when  all my signals complete and all signal references are nulled, i see a few RAC* objects still alive in the memory when i checked through instruments. Is this intended  or is my code leaking memory? When i run the signal, there is an activity surge where i see a lot of RAC objects getting allocated and then it falls back to this state as shown the the below screen capture.

Every subsequent invocation ends in this same state. So i am not very worried about it btw.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C3yD.jpg

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are all shared global instances that RAC uses so it doesn't need to allocate memory for every use of them. I'm sure there's a fancier word for that optimization, but I can't think what it is. For example, check out `RACUnit`:

```
+ (RACUnit *)defaultUnit {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static RACUnit *defaultUnit = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      defaultUnit = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return defaultUnit;
}
```

Since all `RACUnit`s are the same, RAC never bothers to make more than one instance of it. That's all you're seeing.

Comment: It's not a singleton, though -- singleton is a design pattern, an interface level thing. This is an implementation level thing. I guess it's just interning?